# In copula -Transformation to uniform produces error - the integral is probably divergent?

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate a custom distribution for my data on home prices for new york(ny) and boston(boston). I fit uni-variate skewed t distribution for my marginals and then transformed the data to uniform in R. This is where i am coming across problems. While creating the transform for boston series, R produces an error - "Error in integrate(fp, 0, Inf, Ocor, alpha, nu, z, ...) : 
  the integral is probably divergent".

And this is the program i used which has been borrowed from the examples of the book - Statistics and Data Analysis for Financial Engineering by David Ruppert.

```
    data=read.csv("homeprice.csv", header=T)
summary(data)

ny=data$ny
boston=data$boston

library(MASS)
library(fCopulae)
library(copula)
library(sn)

x1=ny
x1s = sort(x1)

fit1 = st.mple(y=x1)
est1 = fit1$dp
u1 = pst(x1,dp=est1)
n = length(x1)

x2=boston
x2s = sort(x2)
fit2 = st.mple(y=x2)
est2 = fit2$dp
u2 = pst(x2,dp=est2)
```

My Question is how do I correct this error?   My data is shown below. Thanks

> ny=c(47.14
>   47.32
>   47.82
>   48.59
>   49.57
>   50.64
>   51.9
>   53.21
>   54.55
>   55.19
>   55.83
>   56.51
>   57.62
>   58.48
>   59.39
>   60.72
>   62.27
>   64.06 66
>   67.79
>   69.47
>   70.76
>   71.76
>   73.32
>   74.42
>   75.43
>   76.25
>   77.34
>   79.16
>   80.84
>   82.22
>   83.01
>   83.44
>   83.88
>   84.02
>   84.41
>   84.12
>   83.92
>   83.48
>   83.71
>   84.23
>   84.59
>   85.02
>   85.33
>   85.54
>   85.14
>   84.82
>   84.33
>   84.32
>   83.77
>   83.27
>   82.94
>   82.97
>   82.95
>   82.67
>   82.63
>   82.38
>   82.36
>   81.85
>   81.32
>   80.89
>   80.53
>   79.99
>   79.34
>   79.05
>   78.96
>   78.78
>   78.21
>   77.41
>   76.8
>   76.14
>   75.6
>   74.59
>   73.69
>   72.87
>   72.29
>   72.63
>   73.5
>   74.39
>   74.9
>   75.06
>   75.01
>   74.84
>   74.74
>   74.59
>   74.38
>   74.27
>   74.4
>   74.69
>   75.14
>   75.47
>   75.79
>   75.74
>   75.48
>   75.38
>   75.35
>   75.54
>   75.42
>   75.32
>   75.34
>   75.71
>   76.44
>   76.84
>   76.99
>   76.99
>   76.92
>   76.88
>   76.71
>   76.61
>   76.43
>   76.6
>   76.88
>   77.55
>   78.2
>   78.78
>   79.08
>   79.08
>   78.87
>   78.5
>   78.36
>   78.28
>   78.29
>   77.95
>   77.77
>   78.03
>   78.58
>   78.99
>   79.17
>   79.17
>   79.11
>   78.85
>   78.7
>   78.63
>   78.73
>   78.9
>   78.94
>   79.36
>   79.52
>   79.97
>   80.31
>   80.45
>   80.35
>   80.02
>   80.03
>   80.08
>   80.08
>   79.97
>   80.03
>   80.53
>   81.53
>   82.32
>   82.72
>   82.8
>   82.84
>   82.94
>   83.11
>   83.36
>   83.85
>   84.28
>   84.76
>   85.52
>   86.58
>   87.7
>   88.48
>   89.04
>   89.31
>   89.41
>   89.43
>   89.49
>   89.89
>   90.56
>   91.59
>   92.49
>   94.07
>   95.47
>   96.88
>   97.67
>   98.24
>   98.59
>   99.28 100
>   100.54
>   101.27
>   102.41
>   104.35 106
>   107.52
>   108.9
>   109.76
>   110.51
>   110.89
>   111.87
>   112.66
>   113.51
>   114.48
>   115.6
>   116.38
>   117.9
>   119.66
>   121.41
>   122.91
>   123.86
>   124.74
>   124.72
>   125.19
>   125.4
>   126.5
>   127.93
>   129.89
>   132.2
>   135.18
>   137.74
>   139.69
>   141.58
>   143.29
>   145.2
>   146.55
>   147.3
>   148.38
>   149.53
>   150.88
>   151.86
>   153.5
>   155.14
>   157.1
>   158.73
>   160.59
>   162.31
>   163.63
>   164.92
>   166.61
>   168.3
>   170.52
>   172.9
>   175.74
>   177.93
>   179.79
>   181.9
>   183.69
>   185.16
>   187.19
>   189.29
>   192.17
>   194.1
>   195.96
>   197.77
>   199.86
>   202.33
>   204.83
>   207.64
>   210.3
>   212.68
>   213.5
>   214.47
>   214.33
>   214.97
>   215.57
>   215.83
>   215.25
>   214.34
>   214.09
>   214.29
>   214.24
>   213.79
>   212.78
>   212.52
>   212.4
>   211.62
>   210.51
>   209.49
>   208.37
>   207.18
>   206.39
>   205.54
>   204.38
>   202.09
>   200.44
>   198.31
>   196.52
>   194.72
>   194.23
>   194.74
>   193.7
>   193.48
>   191.66
>   189.66
>   186.52
>   183.45
>   180.93
>   177.84
>   173.6
>   170.69
>   171.17
>   172.34
>   173.91
>   175.13
>   174.81
>   174.42
>   172.65
>   171.85
>   171.39
>   170.56
>   169.26
>   168.89
>   170.47
>   172.85
>   175.02
>   175.18
>   174.43
>   171.5
>   169.53
>   167.92
>   165.92
>   164.45
>   162.34
>   163.92
>   165.09
>   166.82
>   169.54
>   170.2
>   169.96
>   167.33
>   164.86
>   162.41
>   160.63
>   158.87
>   157.4
>   157.95
>   160.18
>   163.27
>   165.17
>   166.41
>   166.3
>   165.16
>   162.88
>   161.96
>   161.23
>   161.46
>   160.25
>   161.97
>   164.64
>   167.96
>   170.47
>   172.29
>   173.23
>   173.29
>   172.72
>   171.96
>   171.97
>   171.29
>   170.6
>   170.81
>   172.32
>   175.14
>   177.1
>   177.89
>   177.53
>   176.49
>   175.08
>   175.18
>   175.33
>   175.6 )
>
> boston=c(43.35
>   44.29
>   45.31
>   46.8
>   48.09
>   49.66
>   51.13
>   53.14
>   54.59
>   55.81
>   56.74
>   57.91
>   58.81
>   59.72
>   60.67
>   61.56
>   62.93
>   64.75
>   66.48
>   67.42
>   68.1
>   68.91
>   69.59
>   70.07
>   70.04
>   70.08 70
>   70.7
>   71.51
>   72.32
>   73.09
>   73.79
>   74.39
>   74.63
>   74.83
>   74.74
>   74.4
>   74.02
>   73.4
>   73.78
>   74.46
>   75.07
>   75.53
>   75.47
>   75.38
>   75.25
>   75.01
>   74.79
>   74.23
>   74.59
>   74.48
>   74.63
>   74.73
>   74.63
>   74.68
>   74.07
>   73.71
>   73.38
>   73.31
>   73.02
>   72.76
>   72.28
>   71.19
>   70.91
>   70.42
>   70.14
>   69.84
>   69.56
>   69.3
>   68.72
>   67.36
>   66.13
>   64.97
>   64.17
>   63.57
>   63.35
>   63.84
>   64.25
>   64.49
>   64.79
>   64.83
>   64.71
>   64.05
>   63.69
>   63.18
>   62.94
>   62.97
>   63.69
>   64.09
>   64.38
>   64.46
>   64.75
>   64.63
>   64.62
>   64.17
>   64.29
>   64.44
>   64.26 64
>   63.98
>   64.56
>   65.43
>   66.11
>   66.62
>   66.62
>   66.46
>   66.33
>   66.27
>   66.36
>   66.31
>   66.65
>   67.26
>   67.63
>   68.46
>   68.84
>   69.27
>   69.25
>   69.21
>   68.88
>   68.48
>   68.3
>   68.19
>   68.31
>   68.23
>   68.79
>   69.75
>   70.44
>   71.04
>   70.94
>   70.69
>   70.19
>   69.93
>   70.15
>   70.08
>   70.57
>   70.88
>   71.52
>   72.47
>   73.24
>   73.98
>   73.86
>   73.9
>   73.58
>   73.84
>   74.02
>   73.93
>   74.48
>   74.92
>   75.86
>   76.9
>   77.61
>   78.14
>   78.33
>   78.64
>   78.77
>   78.94
>   79.24
>   79.48
>   80.2
>   81.07
>   82.55
>   84.12
>   85.42
>   86.4
>   87.19
>   87.32
>   87.14
>   87.45
>   88.48
>   89.26
>   90.14
>   91.17
>   92.79
>   94.29
>   96.08
>   97.27
>   98.33
>   99.13
>   99.67
>   100.01 100
>   100.36
>   101.31
>   103.27
>   105.85
>   108.48 110
>   111.38
>   112.67
>   114.11
>   115.36
>   116.56
>   117.67
>   118.51
>   119.94
>   121.54
>   123.11
>   125.12
>   126.76
>   128.26
>   129.62
>   130.51
>   130.94
>   130.06
>   129.93
>   129.63
>   131.21
>   133.34
>   136.76
>   139.56
>   141.77
>   143.66
>   145.85
>   147.43
>   148.33
>   147.28
>   146.79
>   147.18
>   148.99
>   150.42
>   152.15
>   153.3
>   154.21
>   154.97
>   156.38
>   157.63
>   158.63
>   158.58
>   158.54
>   159.19
>   161.1
>   164.29
>   166.59
>   168.57
>   169.69
>   170.9
>   172.18
>   173.97
>   174.04
>   173.42
>   173.43
>   174.76
>   176.92
>   179.04
>   181.17
>   181.33
>   181.9
>   181.67
>   182.45
>   182.07
>   181.69
>   179.44
>   178.17
>   176.28
>   177.12
>   177.62
>   178.61
>   177.9
>   177.79
>   177.28
>   176.34
>   175.72
>   172.59
>   170.31
>   168.29
>   168.04
>   168.52
>   169.61
>   170.96
>   171.29
>   171.77
>   170.84
>   170.73
>   169.33
>   167.39
>   164.58
>   162.59
>   160.31
>   158.52
>   158.68
>   160.34
>   162.29
>   162.56
>   162.73
>   160.98
>   159.17
>   155.03
>   153.05
>   150.73
>   148.77
>   145.83
>   146.45
>   148.77
>   152.71
>   154.53
>   155.94
>   155.62
>   154.71
>   153.98
>   153.78
>   153.01
>   151.42
>   151.39
>   153.56
>   155.95
>   157.83
>   158.83
>   158.35
>   156.27
>   154.34
>   152.76
>   152.52
>   152.18
>   149.83
>   147.33
>   147.06
>   150.89
>   154.46
>   155.75
>   155.58
>   154.39
>   152.7
>   150.33
>   148.53
>   147.87
>   146.26
>   145.95
>   147.16
>   150.63
>   154.4
>   157.18
>   158.26
>   157.25
>   155.11
>   153.71
>   153.81
>   153.8
>   153.9
>   155.71
>   159.13
>   161.94
>   164.75
>   167.02
>   168.26
>   169.02
>   168.42
>   168.78
>   168.65
>   167.82
>   166.98
>   168.44
>   173.58
>   175.4
>   176.3
>   176.51
>   176.72
>   176.64
>   175.78
>   175.44
>   175.05
>   175.61
>   175.3 )

Answer (score 0):

The error means that it fails to integrate the density function - recall that probability is sum under the density function.

It may be that the data is not likely to follow the skewed t-distribution and others may be sought instead. Its doc illustrates the distribution becomes the usual Student (or un-skewed) t-distribution when `alpha = 0` or skewed normal distribution when `nu = Inf`. Hopefully these distributions can approximate the true distribution relatively well - recall that the t-distribution converges to the normal distribution as the number of samples goes to infinity. There's another option of the skewed-Cauchy distribution when `nu = 1` but I'm not sure if it fits in the context.

```
# skewed t distribution (u2 in question)
fit.st <- pst(x2, xi = est2[1], omega = est2[2], alpha = est2[3], nu = est2[4])
#Error in integrate(fp, 0, Inf, Ocor, alpha, nu, z, ...) : 
#  the integral is probably divergent

# alpha = 0, usual Student t-distribution
fit.t <- pst(x2, xi = est2[1], omega = est2[2], alpha = 0, nu = est2[4])

# nu = 0, skewed normal distribution
fit.sn <- pst(x2, xi = est2[1], omega = est2[2], alpha = est2[3], nu = Inf)

# nu = 1, skew-Cauchy distribution
fit.sc <- pst(x2, xi = est2[1], omega = est2[2], alpha = est2[3], nu = 1)
```

@ indu mann

I don't fully understand how the pdf is integrated so that it is not possible to set/limit/control the parameters appropriately.

Instead, if there're some alternative distributional forms of interest, it'd be possible to fit when the skewed-t distribution fitting fails. As an example the skewed normal distribution is fitted when the original fails using `tryCatch()` below.

```
myfit <- function(x) {
  require(MASS)
  require(fCopulae)
  require(copula)
  require(sn)

  fit <- st.mple(y = x)
  est <- fit$dp
  tryCatch({
    dist <- "skewed-t"
    u <- pst(x, xi = est[1], omega = est[2], alpha = est[3], nu = est[4])

    list(dist = dist, u = u)
  }, error = function(c) {
    message("skewed-t fitting failed\nskewed-normal is fit")
    dist <- "skewed-normal"
    u <- pst(x, xi = est[1], omega = est[2], alpha = est[3], nu = Inf)

    list(dist = dist, u = u)
  })
}

fit.ny <- myfit(ny)
fit.ny$dist
#[1] "skewed-t"
fit.ny$u[1:3]
#[1] 1.380398e-302 1.439627e-302 1.615437e-302

fit.boston <- myfit(boston)
#[1] "skewed-normal"
fit.boston$u[1:3]
#[1] 0.001140101 0.001606957 0.002290938
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you Kim for taking time to answer my question. It worked for normal distribution. I am yet to try cauchy and t and I will. Is there a way to know the univariate distribution beforehand which can save us time. I tried using the descdist under the library fitdistrplus but it only gives a set of parametric distribution to choose from. Secondly I also want to share with you the contour plots of my fitted copulas to the data alongwith the inference. I dont know if can do it in the comment section.